# Would a question about the recent deal between Marvel Studios and Sony Pictures be on topic?

Tags: discussion

Marvel Studios and Sony Pictures recently came to an agreement regarding Spiderman and his related characters. Would a question about that agreement, including details on who owns what and how each party can use the character, be on topic?

The tour of the site claims that "Behind-the-scenes and fandom information" questions are on-topic, but I thought it would be best to check here first.

Comment: Not sure where this falls.  If it's about the technicals of the agreement it might not be. Bear in mind I've already asked a really similar question and it got messed to the movies stackexchange

Comment: Note that the actual terms of any formal agreement between the studios is held confidential so any answers will only be based on a handful of (contradictory) answers given at press conferences.

Comment: @Pureferret I've asked it in the Movies and TV Exchange at the moment, but the community on Sci Fi and Fantasy is much better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you've noted, the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) states:

> Ask about...
>
> - Plot, character, or setting explanations
> - Historical or societal context of a work
> - **Behind-the-scenes and fandom information**
> - Story identification
> - Franchise/series reading or viewing order

(emphasis mine).

I think this should fall under "behind-the-scenes and fandom information" and should therefore be on topic, *provided* that you ask about its impact on the franchise / canon. (In other words, questions about how much money went where should be off topic).