# Why was the "two Hulk films" question closed?

Tags: support, closed-questions, closing-questions

Please help me understand why this question was closed:

> [Why were there two Hulk origin films within five years of each other?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122958/why-were-there-two-hulk-origin-films-within-five-years-of-each-other)

I cannot work it out from the brief close reason:

> "This question does not appear to be about science fiction or fantasy within the scope defined in the [help center](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)."

nor from [the only explanatory comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122958/why-were-there-two-hulk-origin-films-within-five-years-of-each-other#comment306931_122958):

> VTC as this seems to be more of a business-based question than a scifi one.

since this reason is not listed in the [help center](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that [behind-the-scenes information is firmly on-topic](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: It's been reopened now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the close timeline [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/122958/timeline). Only one user stated their close reason;

> "VTC as this seems to be more of a business-based question than a
>   scifi one".

For the record (and assuming that's the reason the other users chose to close the question) they were acting in error. [Behind the scenes info about Science Fiction and Fantasy properties](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is firmly on-topic on SFF:SE and well within the scope of acceptability.

The question has been reopened now so no real harm has been done, other than making us relive memories of Hulk.

Comment: You shouldn't make him, Ang Lee.

Comment: Is your real name "[Stewart Lee](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHC13MYcrR4)"?

Comment: (Don't waste your time on that video...!)

Answer (score -4):

I was (and still am) on the fence with this one.

The type of [on-topic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) question this falls most closely under is

> Behind-the-scenes and fandom information

In my case, I voted based on my interpretation of your question and what the help center means by "behind the scenes". I interpreted your question as one of "why did the movie studio reboot a film in just a few years?". As the VTC comment indicates, this is a business-based question (or "financial", in your words) which for most movies doesn't have anything to do with sci fi/fantasy. The accepted answer indicates that the film was rebooted not for a sci fi/fantasy reason but because it used

> a new director and an all new cast

The community seems to be divided on the help center's meaning of the "behind-the-scenes". For one, five distinct users voted to close your question and five distinct users voted to re-open it. As far as meta goes, there is an [old meta question asking about the meaning of "behind the scenes"](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2944/what-type-of-behind-the-scenes-questions-are-on-topic) which seems to support just about any "behind the scenes" question. On the other hand, there is a [more recent meta question about studios' decisions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6567/would-a-question-about-the-recent-deal-between-marvel-studios-and-sony-pictures/6568#6568) which suggests that some "behind the scenes" questions aren't on-topic. In particular, the accepted answer by @SQB says that

> questions about how much money went where should be off topic

So financial "behind the scenes" questions -- like yours -- aren't necessarily on topic. At the time of this post, both meta answers have the same score.

I think your question is too much like the financial "behind the scenes" type of the question which the recent meta answer says is off-topic. Furthermore, I think this question would be a better fit for Movies & TV (yes, I know that a question can be asked on any SE site for which it is on topic, even if it is on-topic on multiple sites and was asked on a less relevant one). However, I acknowledge that reasonable arguments can be made on both sides.

Comment: I don't think you can use SQB's answer as much of a basis for changing the site's policy. His remark came at the end of a longer answer.